# Рекурсивное чтение xml файла

Tags: c#, xml

Есть xml файл с заранее неизвестной структурой, необходимо получить массив элементов одного уровня вложенности (размер тоже заранее не известен). Для примера

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>val1</c>
      <d>val2</d>
   </b>
   <e>val3</e>
   <f>val4</f>
</a>
```

В данном случае необходимы массивы с `b`, `e`, `f` и другой с `c` и `d`. Исходя из входных условий использую `XmlReader` и метод `ReadSubtree`, но он возвращает часть xml вместе с узлом в котором он сейчас находится курсор. Как можно выбрать часть xml которая вложена в узел?

Использую код вида

```
static void recursive_read(XmlReader xmlr)
        {
            while (xmlr.Read())
            {
                xmlr.MoveToContent();

                if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "Element")
                {
                    var innerxml = xmlr.ReadInnerXml();
                    var inreader = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(innerxml));
                    recursive_read(inreader);
                }
                else if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "Text")
                {

                }
                else if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "EndElement")
                {

                }
            }
```

Но если в родительском элементе более одного элемента, то получаем ошибку

> "Существует несколько корневых элементов"

Comment: Если в итоге массивы будут содержать все узлы XML документа, то в чём смысл использовать `XmlReader`? Почему бы просто не загрузить документ целиком в память и работать с ним?

Comment: @PetSerAl забыл написать, так как заранее не известна xml, то не известен и ее размер - если он будет большой, то загрузить не получится в память полностью из-за нехватки памяти

Comment: Но Вы хотите поместить каждый элемент документа в массивы. Если не хватает памяти, чтобы загрузить документ, то её точно также не хватит, чтобы разместить результат.

Comment: @PetSerAl почему? текстовые же значения будут, да и если выбрал значения, можно их использовать, например занести в БД и потом очистить. Вопрос сейчас не в этом.

Comment: Не вижу в коде `ReadSubtree`. Вижу `ReadInnerXml`. Этот метод вернёт несколько внутренних элементов, без родительского. Естественно, они будут восприняты как несколько родительских, что недопустимо в XML.

Comment: И не нужно свойство NodeType преобразовывать в строку. Сравнивайте правильно: `xmlr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `ReadSubtree` возвращает вместе с элементом в котором сейчас курсор, какой в этом толк для рекурсии? Будет бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static List<string[]> recursive_read(XmlReader xmlr)
{
    var childrenNames = new List<string>();
    var result = new List<string[]>();

    while (xmlr.Read())
    {
        if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "Element")
        {
            childrenNames.Add(xmlr.Name);

            var subtree = xmlr.ReadSubtree();
            subtree.Read(); // проматываем текущий элемент

            var subtreeResult = recursive_read(subtree);

            result.AddRange(subtreeResult);
        }
    }

    if (childrenNames.Count > 1)
    {
        result.Add(childrenNames.ToArray());
    }

    return result;
}
```

возвращает список из двух массивов - `[c, d]` и `[b, e, f]`. Если важен порядок - то достаточно поменять `result.Add` на `result.Insert(0, ...)`

Список и массивы строк выбраны наугад. Реальные структуры данных надо подбирать по ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void recursive_read(XmlReader xmlr,string e)
{

    while (xmlr.Read())
    {
        xmlr.MoveToContent();

        if (xmlr.Name != e)
        {
            if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "Element")
            {

                recursive_read(xmlr.ReadSubtree(),xmlr.Name);
            }
            else if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "Text")
            {

            }
            else if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "EndElement")
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пришлось повозиться, но все значения выводит.
Вполне возможно, что данное решение подойдет под задачу.
По крайней мере я ее так вижу.

Comment: 1. Зачем пустые ветви if-else? 2. А в случае самозакрывающихся тегов всё хорошо будет?

Comment: Вы про `<firstname/>` ? Пустые ветки, так как мне необходимы значения в элементах вида <a>val1</a>

Comment: "Вы про <firstname/>?" - Да.

Comment: Они вроде пропускаются если `MoveToContent`, хотя не уверен. Или можно проверять `IsEmptyElement`

Comment: А разве с его помощью можно вернуть массивы? на первом элементе он инициализирует новое поддерево, а нижележащие элементы не обрабатываются

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var innerxml = xmlr.ReadInnerXml();
> var inreader = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(innerxml));
> recursive_read(inreader);
> ```

Так делать не надо. Делай в том же ридере до закрывающего элемента.

> Но если в родительском элементе более одного элемента, то получаем ошибку

Так и должно быть, потому что в валидном xml может быть только один корневой элемент.