# Рекурсивный метод и хранение результатов

Tags: c#

Есть рекурсивный метод. При каждой итерации мне необходимо формировать строку для результатов каждой итерации. Как лучше поступить в данном случае?

Код вида:

```
static void recursive_read()
{   
    while ()
    {
        if ()
        {
            if ()
            {
                recursive_read();
            }
            else if ()
            {
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

То есть все остальные ветки кода должны возвращать значение в переменную.

Comment: Можно передавать в recursive_read() массив строк для хранения результатов. А в конце рекурсии обрабатывать.

Comment: Вы так долго будите блуждать см. Оригинальную задачу: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433147/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-xml-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/433284#433284

Comment: @shoahshoah если знаете что вопрос - дубликат - жмите кнопку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно возвращать значение - возвращайте его

```
static string recursive_read()
{
    var iterationResults = new List<string>();

    while ()
    {
        if ()
        {
            if ()
            {
                var res = recursive_read();
                if (res != null)
                {
                    iterationResults.Add(res); 
                    // или еще как-то добавлять в общему результату этого вызова
                }
            }
            else if ()
            {
            }   
        }
    }

    // тут что-то делать с iterationResults, собирать из них общий someResult
    if (something)
    {
        return someResult;
    }
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня результат собирается из всех веток кода одной итерации

Comment: @e1s в этом примере - тоже. return стоит в конце, кто вам мешает в результат добавлять что-то в любой ветке кода?

Comment: @e1s этот пример решает проблему из вопроса. если вы хотите чтобы  решили какую-то другую - уточняйте вопрос. "У меня результат собирается из всех веток кода одной итерации" - какой результат, как собирается, почему вам решение с просто return не подходит - очень тяжело угадать. практически нереально.

Comment: Я про то будет ли работать, если Вы `List<string>` объявили внутри метода или я что то не понимаю

Comment: @e1s а почему он может не сработать?

Comment: при каждой новой итерации этот список создается заново, допустим первая итерация еще до конца не дошла и вызвала вторую итерацию, что произойдет в таком случае? Результаты первой невыполненной итерации потеряются

Comment: @e1s это ж локальная переменная. в другой итерации будет создан свой список, как-то обработан, превращен в результат. результат вернется в первую операцию, и будет там добавлен в первый спискок.

Comment: @e1s, Результаты первой невыполненной итерации не потеряются, потому что функция еще не отработала и будет ждать пока отработают все вызванные в ней  реккурсивно функции. И то что функиця храниться в это время в памяти, кстати, может вызвать Stackoverflow, если вызывать ее бесконечно.

Comment: Пробую отладчиком, каждый раз `iterationResult` создается заново

Comment: @e1s и? он создается на каждой итерации. заново. чтобы мы могли из него "формировать строку для результатов каждой итерации". скажем, собрать в него список вставляемых данных для текущей ноды (которую обрабатывает текущая операция). если в текущей ноде нет вложенных (список в конце пустой) - вернуть текст из ноды. если есть вложенные - собрать их, выполнить sql, вернуть null.

Comment: @e1s если коротко - рекурсивный метод должен возвращать результат как результат. через return. а не через статику или еще что-то. это ответ на ваш вопрос. результат может быть сложным (не string, а весь список, например). Но суть от этого не меняется.

Answer (score 2):

Использовать коллекцию для хранения результатов, как вариант:

```
static List<string> results = new List<string>();
static void recursive_read()
{   
    while ()
    {
        if ()
        {
            if ()
            {
                results.Add("String, which  you need.");
                recursive_read();
            }
            else if ()
            {

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня результат собирается из всех веток кода одной итерации

Comment: Добавите results.Add("String, which  you need."); куда Вам нужно..

Comment: Можно сделать несколько списков, например, при попадании в if пишем в один список, а при else в другой..